# interest being compounded annually

Tags: finance

What sum would amount to  31,104 in three years at 20% p.a Compound interest, interest being compounded annually  ? (Ans: 18,900)

Solution: 
\begin{align*}
C I &= A – P \\[1ex]
P &= 31104 – P\left( 1 + \frac{20}{100}\right)^3 \\[1ex]
P &= 31104 – P\left(1 + \frac{1}{5}\right)^3 \\[1ex]
P + P\left(1 + \frac{1}{5}\right)^3  &= 31104 \\[1ex]
P + P\left(1+\frac{1}{25}\right) &= 31104 \\[1ex]
P + P\left(\frac{16}{25}\right) &= 31104 \\[1ex]
P \left(\frac{41}{25}\right) &= 31104 \\[1ex]
P &= \frac{31104 \times 25}{41} \\[1ex]
P &= 18,965 
\end{align*}
So answer doesn't match actual answer. please help me.

Comment: Are you sure of the answer?  I see $S\times (1.2)^3=31104\implies S=\frac {31104}{1.728}=18000$.

Comment: Note:  I can't follow your calculation.  You appear to write $(1+\frac 15)^3=(1+\frac 1{25})$ but this is not true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula used isn't right.

For a principal $P$, rate of interest $r$%, time in years $n$, the amount $A$ when compounded annually is given by
$$A=P(1+\frac{r}{100})^n$$
Thus
$$31104=P(1+\frac{20}{100})^3$$
$$31104=P(\frac{6}{5})^3$$
$$P=\frac{31104*125}{216}=18000$$

The principal must be $18000$.

Answer (score 0):

If interest is being compounded annually use the formula-

$$A=p(1+\frac{r}{100})^t$$ instead of calculation for each year.

Note-Here $A$ is the final amount,$p$=initial principle,$r$ is rate of compound interest,$t$ is the number of years.

Answer (score 0):

$A(3)=A(0)(1+0.20)^{3}$

$A(0)=\frac{A(3)}{1.20^3}=\frac{31104}{1.20^3}=18000$